# R I accidentally quit while updating packages

Tags: r

I accidentally hit the wrong keys and killed the updating process.

Now I get these errors and am unable to proceed.

What can I do to fix this?

Can I remove `/usr/lib/R/library` directory, and am I done?

```
    > update.packages()
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Matrix :
 Version 1.3-4 installed in /usr/lib/R/library
 Version 1.4-0 available at https://cran.ism.ac.jp
Update? (Yes/no/cancel)
Warning in install.packages(update[instlib == l, "Package"], l, contriburl = contriburl,  :
  'lib = "/usr/lib/R/library"' is not writable
Would you like to use a personal library instead? (yes/No/cancel)
Error in install.packages(update[instlib == l, "Package"], l, contriburl = contriburl,  :
  unable to install packages
```

Thanks

Comment: `/usr/lib/R` should never be writable by a user, ergo the ability to create your own personal library. And *no*, you should not remove it, that will likely break a LOT of R. Do as it says and create a personal library instead, then install new packages into that. If a package is in both, then R will likely default to what is in your personal library, depending on the order of directories in `.libPaths()`.

Comment: Two possibilities:  use `sudo R` to run R if you're the admin for your system, or answer "Yes" to both questions, and then remember to use `.libPaths()` to attach your personal library.